# how to find range of Normalized Device Co-ordinates?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am very new to OpenGL programming.
I know that NDC ranges for [-1, 1] on both the axis with 0,0 in the center. But I am trying to increase its range and I am doing it via glTranslatef(0,0,-11.0f) which gives me some more room.
But I dont know what my new NDC range is now after this gl call.
Can some body please explain ?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to first try to understand the life of a vertex in OpenGL pipeline (an example [here](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596804824/chmath.html)). Otherwise you will find it very hard to understand what you are doing. It can be frustrating at the begining.

The simple answer to your question is that NDC coordinates are **always** in the range of [-1, 1]. You simply cannot change that and you *shouldn't need* to change that.

What you probably *do want* to change though, is the modelview and perspective matrices so your objects have more space in the screen. For example the `glTranslatef(0,0,-11.0f)` command, moves your object down on the negative Z axis (where "camera" looks at by default i.e. away from your eye). Since your object is farther away it seems smaller, so you have more screen space.

Another set of tutorials I have personaly found helpful is [OpenGL ES from the Ground Up](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.gr/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html) (they are for iPhone but the principles are the same)